# Background scanning in iOS even if app is terminated in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter

I am making an App in Flutter that scans the beacons. I used `flutter_beacon` library for this App. As suggested by David G. Young, a member of AltBeacon library, for background scanning in Android, we can do using `foreground service`. That works absolutely fine in Android.

Now I want to make that functionality in iOS also. So how to scan beacons in iOS even if the App is terminated? Is there any functionality like foreground service in iOS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On iOS you can not run any services, your app can run in the background for playing music or interacting with a bluetooth device. But If the user terminates the app that is it. Unless you are using `CLBeacon` but then the OS is scanning for beacons.

Comment: iOS definitely has a capability to work with bluetooth on background: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html, but it's significantly different from Android, and as above comment mentioned, there's no "service" that can be running at all times. You can have your app woken up periodically to do some work. See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes